# How to show current section in the folder hiearchy in OneNote 2013

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

In Microsoft OneNote 2013, is there a way to show where the current page's section lives in the hierarchical folder structure? In other words, a command to open the folder tree with the current section selected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways:

a) Hover the mouse over the current section tab. A hint will pop up showing the folder hierarchy of the section.

b) Click the Full Page View button. In the top right of the screen the notebook and section hierarchy will be shown.

c) Click on the notebook drop down in the top left beneath the File task bar. Once it is expanded, click the pin in the right hand side of that dialogue. That will permanently set the nav bar on the left side. See [Navigation in OneNote 2013](https://web.archive.org/web/20160204042953/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2012/08/08/navigation-in-onenote-2013.aspx).

Comment: Added 3rd way as sugested by Nick and user230714.

Comment: Am I the only one around here who thinks the individual pages should just be additional nodes in the tree?  Shouldn't the whole thing function as one individual hierarchy instead of a small hierarchy inside a bigger one?  Am I crazy here?

Comment: amazing, how could I ever thank you Fernando? using your third technique added tons of value to me using Onenote, because I can now easily sort code snippets in hierarchical view

Answer (score 3):

This link shows a 3rd way to permanently show the nav panel.  You click on the notebook drop down in the top left beneath the File task bar.  Once it is expanded, click the pin in the right hand side of that dialogue.  That will permanently set the nav bar on the left side.

Here is a link with further instructions: https://web.archive.org/web/20160204042953/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2012/08/08/navigation-in-onenote-2013.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this page: https://web.archive.org/web/20160204042953/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2012/08/08/navigation-in-onenote-2013.aspx
They say it is possible to switch back to the old Notebook Pane View (or folder hierarchy, as you call it) from 2010 by clicking on the pin button in the notebook dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. Just pinning the Notebook Pane View doesn't show where the page is in the hierarchy, though. It hightlights the notebook but doesn't hightlight the section group and section. In that page I found another way, though.